# Finding nth div of a certain class with .eq

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="MyDiv">

  <div class="MyClass">test1</div>
  <div class="MyClass">test2</div>
  <div class="MyClass">test3</div>
  <div class="MyClass">test4</div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to use the jquery eq function and so far I have this:

```
function(TheIndex) {
  alert( ('.MyClass').eq(TheIndex).html() );
};
```

I'm getting this error in Chrome

**Uncaught TypeError: Object .MyClass has no method 'eq'**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You're missing the `$` selector and a trailing `'`

Comment: Im' guess you mistyped your code? there's no jQuery or $, and there's an unterminated string.

Comment: That doesn't even look like real JavaScript code.

Comment: It seems that the `$` is missing, as several have pointed out. It's impossible to say though, as you have posted some other code than the one that you are actually using. The posted code has a syntax error, so it won't run at all, so it can't produce the error message that you mention. If possible post the actual code that you are using, or a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(TheIndex) {
    alert( $('.MyClass').eq(TheIndex).html() );
};
```

Remember that the index is going to be zero based, too...

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to:

```
alert( $('.MyClass').eq(TheIndex).html() );
```